# Workbox 5.1.2 backgroundSync Queue configuration

Tags: workbox, background-sync

I have recently migrated from Workbox 3.5.0 to Workbox 5.1.2

I am using Workbox SW via CDN

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js');
```

I have updated my service worker file to use the latest Plugin Classes and have renamed the classes appropriately - everything is working great!

The only real issue / confusion I am having is with the backgroundSync module.
I have read through the documentation and have searched on Stackoverflow & Google for a solution / suggestion, but can't find anything that explicitly answers my question.

I am trying to add failed requests to a Queue that get retried once the network is restored.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/\/php\/postPO.php/'),
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [
      new workbox.backgroundSync.BackgroundSyncPlugin('po-data-queue', {
      maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 * 2 
      })
    ]
  }),
 'POST'
);


const queue = new workbox.backgroundSync.Queue('po-data-queue-2');
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const promiseChain = fetch(event.request.clone()).catch((err) => {
    return queue.pushRequest({ request: event.request });
  });
event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});
```

I know the above code doesn't work because if I give the 2 Queue names the same name then an error is thrown about using unique Queue names. Do I need both functions to use the backgroundSync module or is it one or the other.
Also, do I need to create the indexedDB myself or does workbox handle this?
When using workbox 3.5.0 I created the indexedDB and added failed requests like so (which worked fine):

```
function createIndexedDB() {
  if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {return null;}
  return idb.open('pos-data-queue', 1, function(upgradeDb) {
    if (!upgradeDb.objectStoreNames.contains('events')) {
      const eventsOS = upgradeDb.createObjectStore('events', {keyPath: 'key', autoIncrement: true});
    }
  });
}

const dbPromise = createIndexedDB();
function saveEventDataLocally(events) {
  console.log(events);
  if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {return null;}
  return dbPromise.then(db => {
    const tx = db.transaction('events', 'readwrite');
    const store = tx.objectStore('events');
    return Promise.all(events.map(event => store.put(event)))
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    tx.abort();
    throw Error('Events were not added to the store');
   });
 });
}

const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('pos-data-queue');
const networkWithBackgroundSync = new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
  plugins: [bgSyncPlugin],
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /\/php\/postPO.php/,
  networkWithBackgroundSync,
 'POST'
);
```

I can't wrap my head around how this works, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to use both `BackgroundSyncPlugin` and `Queue`. A unique name is required for each instance. The IndexedDB entries are managed by Workbox itself.

In your code examples I see a suspicious space (making the regex invalid) when registering `BackgroundSyncPlugin`:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp(' /\/php\/postPO.php/'),
                                          ^
```

Maybe you can try with:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/\/php\/postPO\.php/,
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [
      new workbox.backgroundSync.BackgroundSyncPlugin('po-data-queue', {
        maxRetentionTime: 2 * 24 * 60 // two days
      })
    ]
  }),
 'POST'
);
```

The above will work for any URL that contains `/php/postPO.php`. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/r7P0fG/1).

The official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) showcase some examples and how to test if the background sync is actually working.

Comment: Sorry - the RegExp mistake was caused by copy & pasting into stackoverflow and trying to format the code! - Thanks for your suggestion / solution - so passing in 'po-data-queue'  will create the db and populate it - I was initially creating this db myself!